# SIM800L stays in 1sec-blink-state

Tags: sim800

I've bought such on Amazon. My main problem is that it stays in 1sec-blink, meaning it can't registrer cellular network.

First I tried with all anntennas possiblities (one of each, both, none) - failed.

Using NodeMCU (for 3.3 TxRx) and `SoftwareSerial.h` to communicate. It answers all AT command as expected.

I tried several powering possibilities (as noted extensively about 2A on the internet), including 18650 , 2000mAh battery connected only to SIM800L module with no MCU connected, still same state.

What Can be done else?

SEE PELEPHONE:
[image: Carrier support - "PELEPHONE"]

Comment: is the SIM card valid?

Comment: @jsotola AT command replies with sim’s serial number, I guess it is ok

Comment: Are you connecting to a suitable network? Not all networks will work with SIM800L. GSM/GPRS is obsolete now and being gradually switched off by operators around the globe.

Comment: @Majenko See network properties (PelePhone)

Comment: You're with PelePhone? Well, 2G says "N/A". So no, simply no.

Comment: @Majenko Meaning that only 2G capable networks can apply?

Comment: Correct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2G -- For PelePhone you need an LTE or better modem.

Comment: @Majenko Thank you very much! Based on that table, can you point which carrier can I use using SIM800L (since neither are not 800, if it refered to freq).
THNX

Comment: The 800 in SIM800L does not refer to the frequency. The SIM800L works on 850/900/1800/1900MHz. So pretty much any 2G network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mobile network provider does not provide a 2G (GPRS / GSM) network.

2G is graduallly being phased out around the globe, so switching to an LTE modem is really the way forward.

If you still want to use the SIM800L then you need a network provider that gives 2G services. Fortunately the SIM800L is a "quad band" modem, so it will work with pretty much any 2G provider (it works on 850/900/1800/1900MHz, hence the "quad" of "quad band").